# Oracle PLSQLAssociative array greater than 4000 characters c# issue

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql, varchar

Save data in oracle database 11g using pl sql associative array with each String[] array in C# having greater than 4k characters. Following is code:

```
public Boolean InsertIntoDummy(String[] dataMasterDetail)

  {

   OracleParameter p1 = new OracleParameter();

   p1.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;

   p1.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;

   p1.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;

   p1.Value = dataMasterDetail;

   p1.Size = dataMasterDetail.Length;

  p1.ArrayBindSize = Enumerable.Repeat(12000,dataMasterDetail.Length).ToArray();

}
```

I expect that when my dataMasterDetail has greater than 4k characters for each row then data must be processed without any error.

Error received-

> ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Thanks,
Sachin

Comment: I don't know much about Oracle, but I know that `OracleDbType.Varchar2` which you use is limited to 4000 characters, so this exception seems reasonable to me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154163/what-is-the-limit-for-varchar2-in-a-table-of-type-in-oracle

Comment: Can anybody suggest me way to do this in Oracle 11g ,I want to post data greater than 4k